# Quadratic Integer Programming

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, integer-programming, quadratic-programming, discrete-optimization

Would anyone mind helping me solve this problem

$$
\min\space f(x) = \frac12 x^\mathrm TQx + bx + c  \qquad \text{s.t. } \sum_i x_i=\lambda
$$

where $x$ is a vector whose entries are positive *integers* and $Q$ is positive definite.

Comment: Are $b$ and $Q$ also integer-valued?

Comment: yes they are integer-valued.
actually, Q= 2*(I + [1]), b=$\lambda e$ where I is the Identity matrix and [1] is a matrix who all its elements are 1. and e = [1 1 .... 1]' –

Comment: e is a vector whos entries are all one.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that $b = \lambda e$ when I asked that.

Comment: Your welcome i corrected it.

Comment: Have you tried reading up on books about quadratic programming? It is a well-understood area of mathematics. I think what you need is a reference.

Comment: You know. The answer of quadratic programming to this question is $x_i=\frac\lambda p $ for all i's where p is size of x. But I want to know what is the answer under the constraints of x being integer-valued.

Comment: I know that is the *mathematical solution*, which is why I asked you if you tried reading books on quadratic *programming*, not analysis. There are a lot of books out there that specialize in those discrete problems.

Comment: Would you mind introducing me some of them please?

Comment: Question is [cross-posted](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/135100/quadratic-integer-programming) to MO and answered there.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for pointing that out!